# Is norm form a polynomial with integer coefficients?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a number field of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Pick an integral basis 
$w_1, ..., w_n$. Then we can define 
$$
N(x_1, .., x_n) = N_{k/\mathbb{Q}}(x_1 w_1 + ... + x_n w_n).
$$
I was wondering how we can show that this is a degree $n$ homogeneous form.
And are the coefficients necessarily in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Johnny T. This was put on hold for lacking sufficient context. It would make the voters happy, if you included something other than just the statement of the problem. For example, have you seen this calculation done in the case $n=2$. By including that into your question (edit it a bit) you would dispell all thoughts that this is an attempt to outsource a homework assignment. Also, reviewing the case of a quadratic extension (when you can write down an explicit integral basis) may have the "side-benefit" of you solving the question yourself :-)

Comment: Or, just add the definition of the norm (to possibly the same effect).